# Avoid coupling when using enum in tests

Tags: swift, unit-testing, enums

Say we have this enum

```
enum Action: String {
    case doThing
    case doOtherThing
}
```

This enum is used this way:

```
func run(action: Action, block: () -> Void)
```

Now, I unit test the `run` method so I need to pass an `Action` this way:

```
func testActionRun() {

    let expect = expectation(description: #function)
    let sut = ActionRunner()

    sut.run(action: .doThing) {
        expect.fulfill()
        // Assert something
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 0.1, handler: nil)
}
```

As I need to test other situations on `ActionRunner`, I ended with a lot of `.doThing` spread over the whole test suite.

The problem is: if I make a change in production code and change `case doThing` to `case doThatThing` now all my test suite fails because there is no a `case doThing`.

The perfect thing would be to declare a dummy `case` in test code to allow something like

```
sut.run(action: .dummyAction) {
}
```

but `enum` does not allow that as it doesn't allows inheritance nor a extension to add a `case`.

The first option that came to my mind was to convert `Action` into a protocol, but that change is unnecessary in production and its only purpose is to accomplish something in test code.

So, is it there another option to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question of how to avoid coupling when using enums is a tricky one. I bumped into that myself a few times with no solid answer :/

One point you raise is the one of using a protocol, and that feels unnecessary in production. I sort of agree with that, but most time it's the necessary evil.

In the example you showed though I think maybe a tweak in the design might solve part of the problem.

In particular when looking at this code

```
func run(action: Action, block: () -> Void) {
    // ...
}

func testActionRun() {

    let expect = expectation(description: #function)
    let sut = ActionRunner()

    sut.run(action: .doThing) {
        expect.fulfill()
        // Assert something
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 0.1, handler: nil)
}
```

What comes to mind to me is that your `Action` specifies a certain behaviour. That is when you test the `run` method passing `.doThing` you expect a different behaviour than when passing `.doOtherThing`.

If that's right, is there any reason why you need to pass the action enum instance *and* an action block to the `run` function?

You could separate the code that defines the behaviour from the one performs the actual action even more that what you've done already. For example:

```
protocol Actionable {
    var action: () -> () { get }
}

enum Action: Actionable {
    case doThing
    case doOtherThing

    var action {
      switch self {
      case .doThing: return ...
      case .doOtherThing: return ...
    }
}

class ActionRunner {
    func run(actionable: Actionable) {
        actionable.action()
    }
}

func testActionRun() {
    let expect = expectation(description: #function)
    let sut = ActionRunner()

    sut.run(actionable: FakeActionable()) {
        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 0.1, handler: nil)
}

class FakeActionable: Actionable {
    let action = { }
}   

func testDoThing() {
    let sut = Action.doThing

    sut.action()

    // XCTAssert for the expected effect of the action
}
```

*Note:* I haven't actually compiled that code, so bear with me if it has some mistakes. It should give the idea though.

This way you have `ActionRunner` which only purpose is to properly run a given `Actionable`, and the `Action` enum which only purpose is to describe what different actions should do.

This example code is rather restrict in what it can do, only run `() -> ()` actions, but you could build on top of it to achieve more advanced behaviours.

Comment: Thank you so much @mokagio. It seems perfect to me, it decouples one thing from another very elegantly.

Comment: Glad you liked my suggestion @emenegro, let me know how it goes :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change your production code you have to change your test code too in order to test those new changes.

Maybe you can set the value on an `Action` variable in the setUp func of your `XCTestCase` class

```
import XCTest

class SharingKitTests: XCTestCase {
    var theAction: Action!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        self.theAction = .doThing

    }
}
```

Then you will be able to use this *theAction* var in all your test methods, and if you need to change the value you only need to change it in one place.

Comment: It is a good approach but that is not the point itself. It is annoying to change every occurrence of `.doThing` but I would use find & replace. Also, when I write tests, I prefer to apply DAMP instead of DRY.

Comment: I had never heard of DAMP. Thanks @emenegro for mentioning it :)